Trying to override the main function in assembly on the Arduino IDE
I'm trying to write pure assembly on the Arduino UNO R4 minima for educational purposes. I do it in the Arduino IDE.
I kept the .ino file and left just a comment inside. I've added a main.S on the side in which I've written the following code:
.global main
main:
  mov r0, #1

Every time I try compiling, I get this error:
multiple definition of `main'

How do I get rid of this error and keep all the code in assembly please ?

The Arduino IDE defines main for you.  You can define setup and loop instead.  Also, if you just never return from setup that is fine.
